# Do I still need a driver for a phone if Windows recognizes it but Visual Studio 2017 doesn't?

Tags: deployment, xamarin.android, driver, device

I have a Xamarin.Andorid project in Visual Studio 2017. I want to deploy the project on a real device. I am following the following steps to do it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/set-up-device-for-development

I have done all the steps until "Install USB Drivers". When I connect the device to the computer via USB cable the computer recognizes it, I can transfer files, photoes etc. from the phone to the computer(Windows 7). My question is do I still need to install drivers for my phone(ZTE Blade A452) if the PC recognize it or is the problem in Visual Studio? 2 years ago I remember deploying Xamarin.Android application on the same device from Visual Studio 2017 in Windows 10, and I followed the steps in the link above untill "Install USB Drivers" , I didn't have to install any drivers and it worked.

Comment: You could deploy your app on another device . In addition , VS 2019 had released , you would better update the IDE and system of PC to latest .

Comment: `You could deploy your app on another device .` I have no other phone but the ZTE Blade A452. `you would better update the IDE and system of PC to latest .` The caracteristics of my PC doesn't support Visual Studio 2019.